# PHP Offset timezone times

Tags: php, timezone, datetimeoffset

I have written a PHP application and I've connceted to another database to display data.

In the database, the data says '2009-12-31 22:30:00'. Their website displays the data as 8:00pm (1.5 hrs off)

How do I convert 2009-12-31 22:30:00 to 8pm in PHP?

The field is $row['field_cck_monday_value']

Answer (score 0):

The "cck" portion says that you're probably dealing with Drupal. Drupal has user-based date formatting and timezone conversion that it runs between the database and the view. Your best bet is to hook into that.

Comment: Yes, it is a Drupal db. I dont know drupal, so this seems far too hard to work out.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract required time from within your query something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(field_cck_monday_value, INTERVAL 90 MINUTE) FROM tbl
```

[Or if you wish, you can set the appropriate time zone for your mysql connection or session.](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-set-timezone-per-connection/)

Comment: Hi Sarfraz, Good answer, but it doesn’t work.... Each time I enter Australia/Brisbane, it simply doesn’t convert it. I tried both the SQL and the connection string approach but not no good….. I also tried it in PHP my admin. Nope :( Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

```
$date = new DateTime(row['field_cck_monday_value']);    
$date->sub($date, new DateInterval('P1.5h'))
```

I'm not certain on the DateInterval, exactly how to format the negative 1.5 hours

Comment: I tried this...  $date = new DateTime($row['field_cck_monday_value']);    
$date->sub($date, new DateInterval('P1.5h'));  And got this error. Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::sub() in /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/index.php on line 154  which is the 2nd line.

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: My guess is that you need to upgrade your version of PHP to use Datetime::sub()  http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php